# getView method displaying text and image in a GridView?

Tags: android, json

i am trying to get text , image from json from web server and put in Grid View
it's ok when obtaining data from the server but the problem is with get view

here is just trying to get the text but it pops up an list of error in logcat concerning the getview method

Logcat error:

```
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at de.vogella.android.twitter.json.ParseJSON$ImageAdapter.getView(ParseJSON.java:211)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:932)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-15 20:51:13.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public class ParseJSON extends Activity {
GridView MyGrid;
Bitmap bmImg;
ImageView imView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        MyGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }


        public String readTwitterFeed() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://www.zigwheels.com/api/zigtvApi.php?method=data&module=News&section=News");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }


        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View MyView = convertView;


            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                 LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                 MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);



            }
            TextView    tv = (TextView)MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);







             try{
                 JSONArray  jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed());

                 String[] values = new String[jsonArray.length()] ;


              for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     if( position < values.length){
                   values[i] =jsonObject.getString("headline");

                   tv.setText(""+ values[position] );
                     }




                }}catch(JSONException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }





            return MyView;
        }



}
























}
```

Comment: here it is i edited the post:)

Comment: If possible, please post the JSON String too.

Comment: the json string is not the problem i tried it on list view and it worked ,

Comment: what you have at `ParseJSON$ImageAdapter.getView(ParseJSON.java:211)` it says that at line 211 you have null check what that is.

Comment: you should set aside json parsing from the getView and set your variable probably at the constructor or as constructor variable to your adapter and only call the values[position] without json parsing in the getView()

Answer (score 0):

If your `position` variable is greater than current `i` in that for, you will get a NullPointerException because you do not have something in values[position] (this is happen because your reset the values array on every call of getView()).

Try something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

               JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

               values[i] =jsonObject.getString("headline");
               if( position < values.length)
                  tv.setText(""+ values[position] );

              // thumbnail[i] =jsonObject.getString("thumbnail");

            }
```

Comment: it gives the same null exception  can i give u the source code because it is driving me made :D??

Comment: Could you show what you have on ParseJSON.java, between lines 200 - 220? Also, posting the JSON string could be helpful.

Comment: it gives the same thing , thanks for your effort , i am inspecting the code now , i am trying a fresh project from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: so how to add text beside images? so i can build the same but on clean version?